# NetworkInfo no funciona

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de identificar cuándo el usuario no está conectado a internet en una app y me encuentro con que, al intentar usar NetworkInfo para ello, la app deja de funcionar. No da ningún error de compilación, pero sé que o que da el fallo es lo que está en el `if` en base a pruebas que he hecho (el problema es que no sé a qué se debe dicho problema):

```
public boolean conectado ()
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Ya he añadido el permiso `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` en el manifiesto, pero sigue sin funcionar.

En el logcat aparece lo siguiente:

```
07-12 14:52:00.548 1533-1533/? I/InstallerConnection: connecting...

                                                      [ 07-12 14:52:00.549  1300: 1300 I/         ]
                                                      new connection
07-12 14:52:00.569 1533-1533/? I/InstallerConnection: disconnecting...

                                                      [ 07-12 14:52:00.569  1300: 1300 E/         ]
                                                      eof


                                                      [ 07-12 14:52:00.569  1300: 1300 E/         ]
                                                      failed to read size


                                                      [ 07-12 14:52:00.569  1300: 1300 I/         ]
                                                      closing connection
07-12 14:52:00.775 1533-1533/? I/InstallerConnection: connecting...

                                                      [ 07-12 14:52:00.775  1300: 1300 I/         ]
                                                      new connection
07-12 14:52:34.277 1612-1612/? W/RichInputConnection: Slow InputConnection: GET_TEXT_BEFORE_CURSOR took 272 ms.
07-12 14:53:17.757 1533-1533/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
07-12 14:53:21.690 2365-2756/? I/FA-SVC: App measurement is starting up, version: 10298
07-12 14:53:22.310 2365-2825/? I/FA-SVC: This instance being marked as an uploader
```

Comment: Ve el logcat y escribemos los que vez cuando se cierra.

Comment: Segun tengo entendido, puede que este equivocado, `isConnected()` no puede utilizarse en el hilo de la vista.

Comment: En ese caso, ¿Cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: Mira esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293646/3590533